# Filter for when the post is updated

Tags: filters, admin, actions

Is there a way to check in admin page if a post was just updated?

It looks like WP shows a notification so there must be a hook but I can't find it..

[image]

I want to trigger some js in the post.php in the admin screen if the post was just updated (post added to database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter you are looking for is [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). This filter is triggered each time you save a post.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function' );
function my_function( $post_id ){
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

This filter passes the post's ID to the callback function, so you have access to everything you need.